# Data Binding a DropDownList in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know this topic has been covered a lot but I cannot find a solution to my problem.

I've tried using SqlDataSource to create a field binding using the following guide but I follow every step and then at the end the option for Field Binding is grayed out. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294.aspx

So I've moved onto trying to code the DropDownList into the GridView, but I don't currently get any data generated in the DDL. Not sure what to add next.

Below is my code for the GridView, I'm trying to get  the ddlCategory to display all the categories from my category table.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="FileID" DataSourceID="filenameTableDataSource"
    EnableModelValidation="True" Style="text-align: center">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileID" HeaderText="FileID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="FileID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Filename" HeaderText="Filename" SortExpression="Filename" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Category" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" />--%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsPublished" HeaderText="IsPublished" SortExpression="IsPublished" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsArchived" HeaderText="IsArchived" SortExpression="IsArchived" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the SQL statement I'm using to get the data for the GridView:

```
SELECT Files.FileID, Files.CategoryID, Files.Filename, Files.Description,
       Files.IsPublished, Files.IsArchived, Categories.Description AS Category 
FROM Files INNER JOIN Categories ON Files.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use OnRowDataBound event :

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{  
    DropDownList ddlCategory= (e.Row.FindControl("ddlCategory") as DropDownList);
    ddlCategory.DataSource = GetData("SELECT DISTINCT CategoryName,CategoryId FROM Categories");
    ddlCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
    ddlCategory.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
    ddlCategory.DataBind();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar struggle, you need to use something along these lines  private void BindDropDownList()

```
        DataView dv = mgr.GetItemSeriesMaster().DefaultView; //how to filter data
        dv.RowFilter = ProductQueryFilter;
        Dropdownlist1.DataSource = dv;

        Dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "Description"; // the items to be displayed in the list items
        Dropdownlist1.DataValueField = "Id"; // the id of the items displayed
        Dropdownlist1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is as below:
Create a Method that would return your DataSet from DataBase like below:

```
private DataSet GetData(string query)
{
string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            sda.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Bind Your GridView to your Data SOurce like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData("SELECT ContactName, Country FROM Customers");
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
}
```

The on the GridView1_RowDataBound event of the gridview do as below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //Find the DropDownList in the Row.
    DropDownList ddlCategory= (e.Row.FindControl("ddlCategory") as DropDownList);
    ddlCategory.DataSource = GetData("SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Category");
    ddlCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
    ddlCategory.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
    ddlCategory.DataBind();




}
}
```